# Create an array of UiImageVIews to feed iCarousel from 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, video, ios7, uiimageview, icarousel

I am trying to create an NSMutableArray of UIImageViews to feed an iCarousel. Each UIImageView is to have a thumbnail of a video and labels for name and length.
I have found that creating the video thumbnails as the iCarousel loads leads to an unacceptable delay once there are more than 10 video thumbnails are loaded. i haven't found an asynchronous way to create the video thumbnails as they are required by the iCarousel.

The current solution I'm trying to make work is to save both the video and a matching thumbnail to the apps documents folder at the time the video is saved. These are then loaded into 2 time sorted arrays ( with exactly the same count ).

The puzzle I'm trying to solve is what is the best way to create the new array of UIImageViews using the thumbnail image from one array and the name and video length from the video with the matching index in the second array.

I was previously creating the thumbs and labels from an array of just the videos using this code.

```
 UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 135.0f)];
    ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"];
    view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

    UIImage *thumb = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:anyPath];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
    imageView.tag = 1000;
    [imageView setImage:thumb];
    [view addSubview:imageView];

    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150.f, 200.f, 25.f)];
    [nameLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [nameLabel setTag:2000];
    [nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.f]];
    [nameLabel setText:anyPath.lastPathComponent];
    [view addSubview:nameLabel];

    UILabel *lengthLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150.f, 200.f, 25.f)];
    [lengthLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
    [lengthLabel setTag:3000];
    [lengthLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [lengthLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.f]];
    [lengthLabel setText:[MediaManager lengthOfVideoWithPath:anyPath]];
    [view addSubview:lengthLabel];
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK the solution was to use a block to create the array of UIImageViews from the 2 Arrays like so ( this loads the carousel quickly)

```
  [self.aryVideos enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id item, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 135.0f)];
    ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"];
    view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

    UIImage *thumb = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:self.aryThumbs[idx]];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
    imageView.tag = 1000;
    [imageView setImage:thumb];
    [view addSubview:imageView];


    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150.f, 200.f, 25.f)];
    [nameLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [nameLabel setTag:2000];
    [nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.f]];
    NSString *path = [item lastPathComponent];
    [nameLabel setText:path];
    [view addSubview:nameLabel];

    UILabel *lengthLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150.f, 200.f, 25.f)];
    [lengthLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
    [lengthLabel setTag:3000];
    [lengthLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [lengthLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.f]];
    [lengthLabel setText:[MediaManager lengthOfVideoWithPath:item]];
    [view addSubview:lengthLabel];


    [self.aryThumbViews addObject:view];
}];
```